# How do I sync two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, synchronization

For a little background information, I am trying to sync two calendars (one of them is the google calendar)

I am using the two APIs to get all the event information from these two calendars and putting them into their own arrays. So that leaves me with:

GoogleEventArray
OtherEventArray

In the long run I would like to do a two-way sync between the two arrays. However, for now to keep it simple I just want to keep OtherEventArray as the Master, and GoogleEventArray as the slave.

I am not looking to just delete the entire google calendar each time I run the script and update it from the OtherEventArray because this script will be on a cron job running every minute or so to keep the google calendar up to date. I just need to check the arrays for changes or needed additions.

So I just need some ideas for the best way to sync these two arrays?

**EDIT**

Maybe a better way would be to find whats different between these two arrays and add it to a third array so I can just use this to save the changes to the google calendar.

Because if I just combine the two arrays into one I still would have to save all this data that hasnt been changed to the google calendar therefore causing unnecessary work load.

Also here are my two arrays with data in them so you can get an idea of things that can change and I need to detect those changes in the title, or date, or description

http://snipt.org/xXW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `array_combine`.

You can do array addition also:

```
$arrFirst = $arrSecond + $arrFirst
```

Comment: Well i dont want to combine the arrays. Sorry a better question is find the difference between the two arrays, and put whats different into a third array. That way the third array is used to update the new information into the google calendar

Comment: this will add/merge them together and quite possibly create duplicates.

Comment: exactly and no one wants a calendar full of dupes :(

Comment: **no duplicates** white doing `+` it will give priority to $arrSecond and add values of $arrFirst if $arrSecond doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge), [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) and the [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/array_uintersect) family of functions. Which you need to use depends on the precise structure of those arrays.

Comment: array_uintersect looks like something I could use, can that be used to return the difference of the two arrays? Im having a little trouble understanding it.

Comment: or maybe I should just use array_diff

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something similar to

```
$a1[md5("event")]
$a2[md5("event")]
```

Where "event" is in fact some string that you create for event such as `"event name"."event datetime"`

If you use same principle for both then when you do merge either via merge method or simple loop event that already exists will simply overwrite each other or you can even check if those already exist.

One thing though, is that this would be good for one way sync. If you change title or something of the event or even event itself to different date and those clash it would overwrite it. You can however make it smarter to let you know or even detect that event has been moved/edited.